# Composer upadate, could not find the config file in windows 10 wamp yii2

Tags: yii2

When I put a command in cmd  "composer update" or "composer status" it gives me config file not found  error:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed composer globally in your system?

Comment: yes i installed composer from this link https://getcomposer.org/download/
and environment vaibale path is C:\Program Files (x86)\ComposerSetup\

Comment: composer.json file is missing in the advanced folder. please read [this][http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html] carefully and follow the instructions.

Comment: composer.json file is already in advanced folder

Comment: just run `composer install` inside the advanced folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file called "composer.json". You can see how to create it in this link: https://getcomposer.org